# how to create a dll of a tcl file

Tags: tcl

1) I want to create a dll file of the below tcl sample code and i am facing lot of troubles while doing this. I am working on linux (ubuntu 10.04) machine.  The name of the file is clock.tcl. I have seen many websites but i couldn't get the exact process to follow.

2) I am also struggling with the exact command on linux to create a dll file of a tcl code

I am new to tcl and creating dll also. Can anybody help me out to solve this problem. Please help me soon.

clock.tcl

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh8.5

package require Tk

namespace eval ::sd {
set time0 0
set value 0
set h_outfile "i"
}

proc every {ms body} {eval $body; after $ms [info level 0]}


proc time_ms { } {

set m [clock milliseconds]
puts " in time_ms time is $m"
set m  [format %2.2d:%2.2d:%2.2d.%2.2d \
[expr {$m/3600000}] [expr {$m/60000}] [expr {($m/1000)%60}] [expr {$m%1000}]]

incr ::sd::value
set ::sd::time0 $m
puts $::sd::h_outfile " \t $::sd::time0 \t $::sd::value \n"
}

proc open_log { } {
set ::sd::h_outfile [open "output.txt" "w"]
puts " file is $::sd::h_outfile"
puts $::sd::h_outfile " \t hr::mm::ss::ms \t temperature in celcius \n"
}


if {$argc < 1} {

open_log
every 100 {
time_ms
}
}
```

Comment: what do you think you mean when you say "dll"? That is a type of file unique to the windows environment, yet you say you are wanting to do this on a linux box. Are you trying to somehow cross-compile the code?  How do you expect to use this "dll"?

Comment: I believe we can do things close to what you want, but some parts are tricky enough (and take enough typing to describe) that we need to know _exactly_ what you're planning to do once you've got this chunk of binary code. Like that, we'll be able to point you in exactly the right direction, rather than giving you something confusingly close-but-not-right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's rare to build Tcl code into a shared library (formally, DLLs are just the shared library format on Windows; other platforms have the conceptual equivalent, but name it differently) but it can be done. The way it is done — well, probably the simplest, but there might be others too — is to build a [StarDLL](http://wiki.tcl.tk/15969). This consists of a Tcl/Tk runtime in a shared library, together with a small virtual filesystem that holds your Tcl code. There are further instructions on [building a StarDLL](http://www.patthoyts.tk/tclkit/building-basekits.html) on Pat Thoyts's page, but it still doesn't seem to be something for the beginner to do.

I question whether this is what you actually need. It's far easier to make a program that you call from elsewhere as an external process, and the tools for packaging as a [StarPack](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3663) are rather more mature.

Comment: There's also [mktclapp](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2545) and [TOBE](http://wiki.tcl.tk/7908) which do similar things, but I've no personal experience with them.

Answer (score 0):

See [Building Tcl DLL's for Windows](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2419)

Comment: first of all, thanks for your reply. But i am working on a linux machnie with ubuntu 10.04 and the above link tells how to create a  dll on windows using visual studio ..etc. Is it not possible to created dll file of a tcl code on linux machine?? If it is possible, i want the help regarding how to do it??